# Codeigniter 404 page not found on server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, codeigniter-3

I deployed a Codeigniter application on the server and I cannot figure out what is causing an:

```
 The page you requested was not found.
```

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

my config.php

```
$config['base_url']    = 'http://188.166.54.225/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

the mod_rewrite is enbled.

I cannot understand the reason, maybe because the controller's names are like this:

```
Login_controller.php
```

?

Debugging Codeigniter.php:

```
if (empty($class) OR ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->directory.$class.'.php'))
    {

            var_dump(empty($class) OR ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->directory.$class.'.php'));//TRUE
            var_dump(empty($class));// FALSE
            var_dump(! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->directory.$class.'.php'));//TRUE
            $e404 = TRUE; 
    }
```

my routes:

```
$route['test'] = 'TestController';

$route['register'] = 'auth/RegisterController/register';
$route['login'] = 'auth/LoginController/login';
$route['logout'] = 'auth/LoginController/logout';

$route['contact'] = 'ContactController/index';
$route['contact/(:num)'] = 'ContactController/index/$1';


$route['create'] = 'ContactController/create';
$route['edit/(:num)'] = 'ContactController/update/$1';
$route['delete/(:num)'] = 'ContactController/delete/$1';
$route['reset_search'] = 'ContactController/reset_search';



$route['default_controller'] = 'ContactController/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

the var dump of APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->directory.$class.'.php:

```
/var/www/phonebook/application/controllers/Auth.php
```

so it is trying to get Auth.php but Auth is a folder and not a file

Comment: Have you tried adding `?` after `index.php` in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: yes, but does not work

Comment: Do you have this problem with your `Login_controller.php` only or everything? also, how are you accessing the Login controller, in other words, what is the link you use and can you post the first few lines where you declare the `Login_controller`'s class.

Comment: I have problem with all the controllers and all have the style like Login_controller.php. The link I use is http://188.166.54.225/login

Comment: <?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_controller extends CI_Controller
{

Comment: Did you change anything in your `routes.php` config file? can you try and add a testing Controller whose name is a simple one word.

Comment: I created this http://188.166.54.225/test controller and it works!!

Comment: Maybe is due to the controller' name with the underscore

Comment: No, I just tried adding `_something` to one of my controllers and it worked fine, there is an `index()` method in the controller right?

Comment: yes there is an index

Comment: I can't seem to find the problem, try putting `var_dump()` around the `CodeIgniter.php` file and see what's wrong.

Comment: where is this file?

Comment: In the `system/core` folder

Comment: how can I surround a file with var dump?

Comment: Not the file... the variables. Read the code and try to debug it.

Comment: I found in codeigniter.php which path it follows to create the 404. This is true : if (empty($class) OR ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->directory.$class.'.php'))

Comment: How is it true? can you `var_dump()` the values in the condition and post the results in the question

Comment: Added in the post

Comment: Do a `var_dump(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->directory.$class.'.php'))`

Comment: /var/www/phonebook/application/controllers/Auth.php

Comment: Check your `config/routes.php` file, you apparently changed something there.

Comment: Edited the post. Auth is a folder in my app not a file like it is trying to look for

Comment: No idea what is the issue